# DAG stages in spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, bigdata

I have created simple word count spark job.

word_count.py :-

```
sc = SparkContext("local","PySpark Word Count Exmaple")
print("0:",type(sc))
print("0:",sc)

# read data from text file and split each line into words
rdd = sc.textFile("file:///home/prashant/hello.txt")
print("1:",type(rdd))
print("2:",rdd)
words=rdd.flatMap(lambda line: line.split(" "))
print("3:",type(words))
print("4:",words)

# count the occurrence of each word
wordmap = words.map(lambda word: (word, 1))
print("5:",type(wordmap))
print("6:",wordmap)
wordCounts=wordmap.reduceByKey(lambda a,b:a +b)
print("7:",type(wordmap))
print("8:",wordmap)

# save the counts to output
wordCounts.saveAsTextFile("file:///home/prashant/spark_output1")
```

This spark job created below two stages.I have attached a screenshot

[image: Stage 0 DAG]

[image: stage 1]

Can someone explain how to read this DAG and make sense out of it?
Another question, reduceByKey() wide transformation is shown in stage 0.
But this was the last transformation done.I was expecting it to be in stage1 instead of stage 0.
How spark divides transformation functions into stages?

Comment: Hello, i think that by mistake both screenshots are the same (stage 0)

Comment: Thnks for identifying. Now its been edited

Comment: Any help on this query?